# Haskell Data.List permutations of functions

Tags: haskell, permutation, ghci

How to fix the permutation error on a list of functions?

```
> :m + Data.List

> permutations [(+1),(-2),(*3)]

No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of `+'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus three others
In the expression: (+ 1)
In the first argument of `permutations', namely
  `[(+ 1), (- 2), (* 3)]'
In the expression: permutations [(+ 1), (- 2), (* 3)]
```

Comment: Never forget that `(-2)` is *not* a section, but equivalent to `(negate 2)`

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell the type of `1` is

```
1 :: Num a => a
```

So Haskell can't decide what `a` to choose in your case. You can fix this with a simple type signature

```
perms :: Num a => [[a -> a]]
perms = permutations [(+1),(subtract 2),(*3)]
```

Comment: The type should be `Num a => [[a -> a]]`, I think.  There's also a problem with `(-2)` being interpreted as a number.  Using `subtract 2` instead fixes that.

Comment: You don't need to decide what the type of `a` is. In fact, your type signature doesn't change anything. The problem was simply with `(-2)`, which will be read as `Num a => a` as others have stated, while the other elements of the list are `Num a => a -> a`.